# Installing Casperjs with codeigniter in WAMP

Tags: windows, phantomjs, casperjs

I am following http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/responsive-screenshots-with-casper/ in order to get started with PhantomJS and CasparJS. Following the directions I have PhantomJS installed in my codeigniter root like so:

```
--application
--system
--index.php
--phantomjs.exe
--casparjs folder
```

I've tested phantom using phantomjs --version and it gives the correct version info so it appears to be installed

After I added:
    E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\myproject\casperjs\batchbin

to the path. I tried:

```
E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\myproject\casperjs\batchbin>casperjs.bat --version
```

and got:

```
'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
myoperable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to add the folder that contains `phantomjs.exe` to your `path` environment variable.